# pass result of json_encode in php to a javascript which is then passed to another javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am a beginner and newbie to this site, I am stuck with my project in hand and would really appreciate some help.

I am using a JQuery plugin written by a third party.
There are 3 javascripts 
i.e. a.js, b.js, c.js

**a.js** is the framework that b.js works under

**b.js** contains a form builder, it contains a function that calls on a JSON array named **selectionOpt** stored in **c.js**

function in b.js is as below

```
createChildren: function () {
        this._super();
        var self = this;

        this.comboselected = new DrawComboBox({
            styles: "comboselected",
            data: Draw.selectionOpt1,
            onChange:function () {
                self.comboselected = self.comboselected.value();
                    }       

   };
 });
```

JSON array in c.js looks like this

```
Draw.selectionOpt1 = [
    {"Id": 1,"data": Blue,"label": "Blue","quantity": 100},
    {"Id": 2,"data": Red,"label": "Red","quantity": 100},
    {"Id": 3,"data": Green,"label": "Green","quantity": 100},
    {"Id": 4,"data": White,"label": "White","quantity": 100},
    ...etc..
    ...etc..
    }
    ];
```

I would like to have the raw data stored in the database (MySQL) instead of c.js
I am struggling with this at the moment. 
I have got a PHP script i.e. api.php written as below

```
<?php 


 include 'DB.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
$colouroptions = Array();                          //fetch result    

while( $obj = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {  
 $colouroptions[] = $obj;  
}


 echo json_encode($colouroptions);  

?>
```

this script returns the following result

```
[["1","Red","Red","100"],["2","Blue","Blue","100"],["3","Green","Green","100"], etc, etc.,...[etc, etc, etc, etc]]
```

Q1: How can I get fetch the data from MySQL and encode it in the desire format?

```
{"Id": 1,"data": Blue,"label": "Blue","quantity": 100},
{"Id": 2,"data": Red,"label": "Red","quantity": 100},
{"Id": 3,"data": Green,"label": "Green","quantity": 100},

etc etc etc
```

Q2: How can I call the JSON array generated from api.php from b.js? or do I need to feed it back to c.js first? How can it be done?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have solved question 1 but am still in search for answer for question 2.
I have trying putting the following code in c.js and it doesn't seem to work
function testAjax() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "api.php"
  });
}
testAjax().success(function (data) { return(data); });


I need the c.js to have a JSON array of objects that is identical to what the php is now returning i.e. echo 'Draw.selectionOpt1 = ' . json_encode($colouroptions) . ';';

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_fetch_object` to let `json_encode` generate the JSON in object notation and not in array notation. the easiest way to load the data into JS is to echo it from PHP like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'Draw.selectionOpt1 = ' . json_encode($colouroptions) . ';';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can now get the api.php to return the desired  result. I am still having trouble with Q2 do, would appreciate if you shed some light on my problem.

Comment: simply use the provided code. then you can just use `Draw.selectionOpt1` in JS

Comment: Sorry I am pretty sure it is just me being super thick, but if I put this in api.php which I tried, how can b.js reads the JSON string if there is no AJAX to load the data?
I tried doing this in main.php 
REPLACING<head><script src="lib/b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="lib/c.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head>WITH <head><script src="lib/b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<?php include 'api.php'?></head>  
It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to understand all the code in the JQuery plugin I am using, but I tried copying the JSON array of objects in b.js and main.php directly, it doesn't work. The combobox would only populate data into the combobox if the JSON array is stored in a separate .js file, or so it seems.

Comment: I also tried doing 'Draw.selectionOpt1 = ' . json_encode($colouroptions) . ';'; in api.php then the following in the <head></head> section of main.php <script src="lib/c.js" type="text/javascript"><script type="text/javascript">
$.get('api.php', function(data) {
  // use the result
  return(data);
});

</script>

Comment: put it before the script which needs to access the data

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. <head><script src="lib/b.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <?php include 'lib/api.php'?></head> Was the code correct, it didn't work the first time round, as the relative URL I was using was incorrect. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_row.
It will create an associative array that will be parsed to your desired json format.

(I don't understand your second question)

Comment: Thanks, changing the code to

     while( $obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {  
     $dateoptions[] = $obj;  
     }

     echo'Draw.selectionOpt1 ='.json_encode($olouroptions) . ';';

gives me the desired result in api.php

Comment: As with the second question.
I need a json array of objects in c.js (which is identical to what api.php is now returning) so the data can be passed to a function stored in b.js
E.g.echo 'Draw.selectionOpt1 = ' . json_encode($colouroptions) . ';';
Is that possible?
I have tried putting the following code in c.js but it doesn't do what I want it to
function testAjax() { return $.ajax({ url: "api.php" }); } testAjax().success(function (data) { return(data); });

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery the ajax function has the ability to pass the returned results through a callback function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // here you can pass the results to another function
    createChildren(data);
  }
});


createChildren: function (passedData) {
        this._super();
        var self = this;

        this.comboselected = new DrawComboBox({
            styles: "comboselected",
            data: passedData,
            onChange:function () {
                self.comboselected = self.comboselected.value();
                    }       

   };
 });
```

Comment: I tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work

function testAjax() { return $.ajax({ url: "api.php" }); } testAjax().success(function (data) { return(data); }); I need the c.js to have a JSON array of objects that is identical to what the php is now returning i.e. echo 'Draw.selectionOpt1 = ' . json_encode($colouroptions) . ';';

Can you please kindly provide further guidance?

Comment: You can't return the results directly through an ajax call but you can pass those results to another function. I'm a little unclear on how all your code works together but you could pass the returned json array directly to a function and execute that function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to get the script to do what I want using the method Andreas suggested. Thanks.

Comment: If @andreas-linden helped you with his answer you should give him an upvote and accept his answer so other people know that was the most useful answer for your problem.